# refreshing html table

Tags: javascript

I'm loading all the data I need for the page as soon as it loads and I want to add a dropdownbox/set of buttons to change the sorting of the data depending on whatever was selected.

Since all the data I need was loaded already, it would be redundant to do a postback and get the same thing again. I think this is possible using javascript but I'm pretty bad at that. BTW I'm doing this on MVC.

so my questions are:

1) If it is possible, how is it done in javascript?
2) Is there another better way to display and refresh the data displayed instead of using tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure Javascript**:

- [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) is a simple way to make your tables *sortable*.

**JQuery**:

- [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) is pretty famous
- [Flexgrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) is also another option, not just for sorting but for making tables/grids get great new features

Aee also [33 JavaScript Solutions for Sorting Tables](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/) for other jQuery and pure javascript options.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to do client-side sorting by javascript. I recommend you use a third-party jQuery library like http://www.datatables.net/. For the simplest setup you just need to give your table an ID and run the script.

```
$("#myTable").dataTable();
```

Of course if you have a lot of rows you need to consider server-side processing instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple answer is:

There are tons of different ways how to do this. Just follow the link and pick the one you like.
I would recommend using jQuery, so i did the search for jQuery Plugins.

[Jquery Tablesort](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=jquery%20tablesort&fp=1&cad=b)