# Convert object to an array so i can sort it?

Tags: javascript

I have a object i that i list in HTML tables. But i want to able to click different columns in this table to "sort" the the data based on that field in question.

As I'm aware of objects are not sorted, so i need to convert it to an array some how ? And then i use href links to call a sort function to sort the array before repopulating the table.

Was hopeing some one may be able to shed light to explain how i do it ?

This is basically how far i got:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game_buildings") or die(mysql_error());
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
            $data[$i][0] = $row['name'];
            $data[$i][1] = $row['id'];
            $i ++;
            }
$data = json_encode($data);
?>
<script>var data = <?echo $data; ?>; </script>
```

Then the table:

```
<table id="list" style="width:70%;margin: 0 auto;" border="1">
    <tr>
  <td align="center">
        <a href="#" onclick='javascript:sort('name')'>Name</a>
      </td>
  <td align="center">
        <a href="#" onclick='javascript:sort('type')'>Type</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

<script>
  for(var key in data){
    result += '<tr><td>'+data[key][0]+'</td><td>'+data[key][1]+'</td></tr>';
  }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += result;
</script>


</table>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, there is `$.makeArray()` for this operation.

Comment: No i don't like to use libraries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` should already be an array. You can verify this by checking the output from `json_encode($data)`:

```
<script>var data = [["foo",1],["bar",2],...];</script>
```

But, `"name"` and `"type"` don't really have any relevance with these, which you seem to want:

```
onclick="javascript:sort('name')"
onclick="javascript:sort('type')"
```

You can change that by keeping the `mysql_fetch_assoc` structure:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

In theory, at least, the output to JavaScript would then be:

```
<script>var data = [{"name":"foo","id":1,"type":...},...];</script>
```

With an array of objects, you can use the [`sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort `data` by the values of the inner objects:

```
function sort(key) {
    data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var A = a[key], B = b[key];

        if (A < B)
            return -1;
        if (A > B)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    });

    // ...
}
```

One way to update the table is to remove the old rows and append new (in place of the `// ...` above):

```
var table = document.getElementById('list');
var oldRows = [].slice.call(table.rows, 1); // 1 = skip the "header" row(s)

for (var r = 0, l = oldRows.length; r < l; r++) {
    oldRows[r].parentNode.removeChild(oldRows[r]);
}

for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].id + '</td></tr>';
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/GB2v3/1/ (albeit, using "id" rather than "type")

With this, you can take the initial loop out of the markup as well:

```
window.onload = function () {
    sort('name');
};
```

Comment: How would my onclick function work - i call sort('something') in the url ?

Comment: @Dave Are you trying to sort it server-side, re-requesting the page with a `?sort=name` query, or client-side reordering table rows within the DOM?

Comment: I want it to be client side - the query does not sort it.

Comment: @Dave In that case, one possible method is to remove the old rows from the DOM and replace them. See my edit for an example (albeit, using "id" rather than "type"). You may also want to look at using a "tablesort" [function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7029631/15031) or [library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992802/refreshing-html-table).

Comment: @Dave Change `sort(0)` and `sort(6)` in the `onclick` attributes to `sort('name')` and `sort('type')`. You may also look at creating a `<tbody>` and use that as your focus to remove/append rows: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/GB2v3/2/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9542/discussion-between-jonathan-lonowski-and-dave)

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple for loop?

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in data) {
    arr.push(data[key]);
}
```

Now sort this with a custom sort function (sorts by name in this case):

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[0] == b[0]) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a[0] < b[0]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: How do i structure the loop for this to add to the "result" variable?

Comment: Do a simple for loop: `for (var key = 0; key < arr.length; key++)` - the rest stays the same.

Comment: Like this:
  for (var key = 0; key < arr.length; key++){
    result += '<tr><td>'+key[0]+'</td><td>'+key[1]+'</td></tr>';
  }

Comment: No, like this: `result += '<tr><td>'+ arr[key][0]+'</td><td>'+arr[key][1]+'</td></tr>';`

Comment: How can i call the function won't arr.sort run automatically?

Comment: Yeah sure, you will need to wrap a function around that (that also rerenders the table etc.).

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle because when i tried it didn't work =/

Answer (score 0):

Mine is not as good as the others : http://jsfiddle.net/andrewbriggs/xndMQ/4/

It could be done better but I'm not that good at javascript